# Compiling a predicate retrieves the whole table before getting the count

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

This executes as `.Count()` on the SQL side:

```
account.SelectMany(acc => acc.Transactions).Count(t => !t.Disabled)
```

and this retrieves the whole table before getting me the count:

```
private Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> transactionsFilterPredicate = t => !t.Disabled;
account.SelectMany(acc => acc.Transactions).Count(this.transactionsFilterPredicate.Compile())
```

Why? I want to be able to extract the predicate as a variable. Is there a way to do it, and still benefit from the SQL-side operation?

**Edit:**

Apparently removing the `.Compile()` part of the code solves the issue... The code still compiles (as in `MSBuild`) and the Count is on the SQL side. What is the benefit of `.Compile()`?

Comment: `Compile` returns a delegate. Not calling compile keeps your variable as an `Expression`. `IQueryable` linq extension methods take Expressions, not delegates. The underlying provider can translate the expression to the appropriate sql by visiting (inspecting) each node of the expression tree and translating to sql. Expressions are a data structure that can be inspected. Extension methods on `IEnumerable` on the other hand accepts delegates and do no such translation (because they can't) . They will require the full data source in memory (full with respect to the last IQueryable call)

Comment: ... The benefit to `Compile` is that you can create delegates that can be invoked. Expressions cannot be invoked, they are basically just data. You can dynamically generate expressions (say, based on user input or some other variavle) and turn them into a delegate that then can be invoked.